# Как в макрос вставить функцию из определенного пространства имен?

Tags: c++

хочу вот так.

```
#define FUNCTION ( name, action ) namespace1::##name::foo( action )
```

ошибка звучит так
src/ .cpp:69:25: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
#define FUNCTION ( name, action ) namespace1::##name::foo( action )

минимальный пример (рабочий):

```
namespace cotrol
{
namespace namespace1
{
    void foo( int x ) {}
} // namespace namespace1

namespace namespace2
{
    void foo( int x ) {}
} // namespace namespace2

} // namespace control

#define ACTION( name, action ) cotrol::name::foo( action )

int main()
{
    ACTION ( namespace1, 5 );
    ACTION ( namespace2, 10 )

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: оно и без `##` не компилирует.

Comment: Что-то это похоже на попытку сколхозить using

Comment: а мне больше похоже на попытку ADL вручную

Comment: ну юзинг в этом варианте не хочется подключать

Comment: Лишний пробел перед скобкой `#define ACTION ( `. Ненужные `##`. отсутствует ; перед  return.

Comment: А в чем смысл таких ухищрений?

Comment: Есть тонна одинаковых функций, но в разных нейспейсах

Comment: Супер, работает!

Comment: Чем `ACTION(namespace1, 5)` лучше `namespace1::foo(5)`?

Comment: чтобы можно было задефайнить пустой макрос. Имеется ввиду один раз написать #ifdef X 
#define ACTION...
#endif // X
чем каждый раз namespace1::foo(5) оборачивать в такое

Comment: Т.е. решалась на самом деле задача условной компиляции, а не подстановки неймспейса.

Comment: @user207200, и тем и тем одновременно